# Getting attribute text from HTML using VBA selenium

Tags: vba, selenium

I need to get the value "8.37" from the "data-rating" attribute.

```
<div class="ch-rating"> "VERYGOOD 8.37"
    <div class="star-rating star-rating--alt star-rating--ch" data-rating="8.37" style="">
            <span style="width: 83.7%;"></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

In java there is `.getAttribute()` but I can't find the syntax in VBA.

I guess its something like this:

`bot.FindElementByXPath("//div[@data-rating]").` followed by some syntax.

Comment: I have would have done in JAVA like this...
`WebElement we = driver.findElement(By.className("star-rating"));
String rating = we.getAttribute("data-rating");`

Comment: I don't know anything about the VBA syntax but I would expect that it exists. If it doesn't you can always use JS to get what you want assuming that VBA has the equivalent of JavascriptExecutor.

Comment: The correct syntax to get the rating is `driver.FindElementByCss("[data-rating]").Attribute("data-rating")`.

Comment: Thank you very much @Florent B. I will use the syntax you provided +1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the value *"8.37"* from the *"data-rating"* attribute you can use the following line of code :

```
bot.FindElementByXPath("//div[@class='ch-rating']/div[@class='star-rating star-rating--alt star-rating--ch']").getAttribute("data-rating")
```

---

### Update 1

### [HtmlElement.GetAttribute Method (String)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.htmlelement.getattribute(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1)

Syntax :

```
var attribute = element.getAttribute(attributeName);
```

where

- attribute is a string containing the value of attributeName.
- attributeName is the name of the attribute whose value you want to get.

---

### Update 2 :

As you are seeing *Run-time error 438: Object doesn't support this property or method* for *HtmlElement.GetAttribute Method (String)* here are some details :

Error 438 occurs when running a program in which a form is assigned to a variable and that variable is used to access a control on the form if the program is on a system running Windows 95 with Regional Settings set to a setting other than English (United States). The error text is:

```
Run-Time Error #438:
Object doesn't support this property or method
```

### Resolution

There are two possible workarounds for this problem.

- Access the form directly rather than by a variable containing the form.
- Create property procedures in the form's code to provide access to the properties of the controls on the form.

### Status

Microsoft has confirmed this to be a bug in the Microsoft products listed at the beginning of this article. This problem has been fixed in Windows 98.

### Trivia

To reproduce this bug consistently, you will need HeapWalker, a utility that ships with the Windows 16-bit Software Development Kit and the 16-bit version of Visual C++.

### Steps to Reproduce :

- From Control Panel, click Regional Settings to open the Regional Settings dialog box. Set the Regional Settings to English (Australian).
- Start the 16-bit edition of Visual Basic 4.0. If it is already running, select New Project from the File menu.

> Source : [FIX: Error 438"Object Doesn't Support This Property or Method"](https://support.microsoft.com/en-in/help/175616/fix-error-438-object-doesn-t-support-this-property-or-method)

Comment: Thanks for your solution. Unfortunately I got an error.  
   Run-time error 438: Object doesn't support this property or method

Comment: Updated my answer. Let me know the status.

Comment: Same error again. I tried with absolute path as well:

Comment: Thank you very much for the information @DebanjanB. I think I will use css finder instead to solve the issue.